# Хеширование пароля с идентификатор $2a$10$

Tags: php, password, password-hash, bcrypt

День добрый.

Нужно записывать пароль с устаревшим идентификатором используя алгоритм шифрования PASSWORD_BCRYPT.

```
password_hash(['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

Comment: И вопрос в чем?

Comment: Как получить  идентификатор $2a$10$ ? В моем варианте получается $2y$10$ ...

Comment: Из мануала сообщают что `BCRYPT` всегда возвращает хеш вида `$2y`. А `$2a` возвращался судя по всему в php до версии 5.3.

Comment: Есть ли способ получить нужный идентификатор не меняя версию пхп?

Comment: Я в этом сомневаюсь.

Comment: Хорошо. Как можно изменить символ 'y' на 'a' в процессе хеширования пароля. Если можно, то с примером.

Comment: @Эдуард  $password = password_hash($_POST['password'],PASSWORD_BCRYPT).str_replace('y', 'a', '$2y$10$'); ?

Comment: И это естественно приведет к неработоспособности сайта.